# SharePoint pnp Powershell nocrawl on a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

How can I set a nocrawl on a list using SPPnp powershell? I tried the following but doesnt work:

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Web $Web.Title -Identity $l
if($list)
{
    write-host $list.Title

    $list.NoCrawl = $true
    $list.Update()
    #$context.ExecuteQuery()
    Invoke-PnPQuery 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by calling the executequery as follows:

`$list.Context.ExecuteQuery()`